# Maven project: method defineClass in class sun.misc.Unsafe cannot be applied to given types with latest Java version

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, unsafe, mvel

I am trying to modify an mvel2 library open source code date back from < 2010.  https://github.com/mvel/mvel

THis is a maven project.

I recently downloaded the source code and when I tried to compile the project, it gives an error message.

```
public Class<?> defineClassX(String className, byte[] b, int off, int len) {
        if (sunJVM) {
            return ((Unsafe) sunUnsafe).defineClass(className, b, off, len);
        }
        else {
            return super.defineClass(className, b, off, len);
        }
    }
```

```
Error message: Error:(59,40) java: method defineClass in class sun.misc.Unsafe cannot be applied to given types;
```

mvel2 2.0.16 seems to have built with Java 1.5 but in my recent environment it is Java 1.8 and the "defineClass" method definition has changed.

New Method definition in Java 1.8  :

```
public native Class<?> defineClass(String var1, byte[] var2, int var3, int var4, ClassLoader var5, ProtectionDomain var6);
```

What is the workaround for this?

Some options I tried:

1. Passsing in null values for ClassLoaded and ProtectionDomain
2. in pom.xml, under:

```
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>-XDignore.symbol.file</compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

```
      a) I tried passing in 1.5 but it fails with same error
      b) Tried the compilerArgs but no luck either?
```

3. Tip from VGR below in the comments to remove the if(sunJVM) block causes all test cases to fail when building the maven package.

I feel the issue seems to be that, since the source code package was built with Java 1.5 and now since I am building with latest Java 1.8 version, it is failing.

Can someone suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: A few years ago, I had to maintain some code which used some methods from (I think?) `sun.misc.*` (Can't be sure, but it was definitely a private SunOS package). This had stopped working due to upgrades to the security of the system. The writer of the code had accessed the methods through reflection (Ughh!). In the end we decided to ditch this (unsafe) functionality.

Comment: `if (sunJVM)`—There is no Sun JVM, since there is no more Sun Microsystems.  So you probably can get ride of that `if` statement and its corresponding body.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, removing the if block causes all test cases to fail when I build the package. Any other workaround on this?

Comment: @mcmattu Did you get a solution for this? I am facing the same issue.